# Is it possible to set by default country to stripe payment sheet?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to set by default country as `UAE`. is it possible to set it? and also is it possible to set it server-side?

All the time it's set United State. But this problem is only on Android and Ios SDK. It's automatically set UAE on [web](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web).

[image: check this country and religion section in this screenshot]

Comment: there is no `country` listed in that link, can you state the exact parameter name and share the snippet of code which you're trying to set this parameter in?

Comment: @alex check my question again. I want to hide or set by default country as UAE

Comment: doesn't look possible, there's no parameter to set the billing details in the PaymentSheet : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/src/types/PaymentSheet.ts

Comment: @alex it means, the user has to select the country from drop-down every payment. isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Specify default values for billing details collected in the payment sheet by setting `defaultBillingDetails`. `PaymentSheet` pre-populates its fields with the values provided.

for iOS Swift

```swift
var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
configuration.defaultBillingDetails.address.country = "US"
configuration.defaultBillingDetails.email = "foo@bar.com"
```

for Android Kotlin:

```kotlin
var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration(...)
configuration.defaultBillingDetails.address.country = "US"
configuration.defaultBillingDetails.email = "foo@bar.com"
```

Comment: val country: String? = null,

configuration.defaultBillingDetails.address.country = "US"

compiler error: val cannot  be reassigned

Comment: @mohsen for iOS swift this solution worked for me thanks, Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

### In React Native CardForm

```
    If want to change the country code then
    defaultValues={{countryCode:'IN'}}
```

### OR,

```
<CardForm
  defaultValues={{countryCode:'none'}}
    onFormComplete={cardDetails => {
      console.log('card details', cardDetails);
      setCard(cardDetails);
    }}
    
    postalCodeEnabled={true}
    placeholder={{
      number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
    }}
    cardStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#000001',
      textColor: '#f2f2f2f2',
      borderRadius: 8,
      borderWidth: 1,
      textErrorColor: 'red',
      placeholderColor: 'grey',
      borderColor: '#ffffff',
    }}
    autofocus={false}
    style={{
      width: windowWidth-8,
      height: windowHeight / 2,
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginHorizontal: 4,


    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/4845
Increase your stripe lib version into

```
Gradle (implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.2.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Native, please provide the defaultBillingDetails when `initPaymentSheet`

You can refer below example

```
  const {error} = await initPaymentSheet(  
   {
     defaultBillingDetails: {
       address: {
        country: 'HK',
       },
     }
   }
  );
```